# android why the ResolveInfo got from resolveActivity() is different than from queryIntentActivities()

Tags: android, android-package-managers

When looking at the `ResolveInfo` return from `resolveActivity()` and `queryIntentActivities()`,

why the `ResolveInfo` is different from these two calls for the same intent?

the `viewIntent` is `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deeplinkData)`, and the one returned from resolveActivity has unrelated packagename/name:

```
ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(viewIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        System.out.println("+++ 111 resolveActivity(), info.activityInfo.packageName:  "+info.activityInfo.packageName+",\ninfo.activityInfo.name: "+info.activityInfo.name);
```

it has log:

```
+++ 111 resolveActivity(), info.activityInfo.packageName: android, 

info.activityInfo.name: com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity
```

where using `queryIntentActivities`

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(viewIntent, 0);
if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {

                System.out.println("+++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.packageName: "+ (info.activityInfo.packageName));
                System.out.println("+++ +++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.name: "+ (info.activityInfo.name));

                ......
            }
        }
```

has log:

```
+++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.packageName: com.client.android.debug
+++ +++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.name: com.client.android.NewsActivity
+++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.packageName: com.android.chrome
+++ +++ queryIntentActivities(), info.activityInfo.name: com.google.android.apps.chrome.IntentDispatcher
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolveActivity()` returns the component that would be started if you call `startActivity()`. That will be:

- `null` if there is no match or you are not set up package visibility rules on Android 11+
- the activity that would be started from some app, if there is exactly one match or if the user chose a default
- the chooser activity, if there are 2+ matches and there is no default

In your case, you are getting the chooser activity (`com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity`).

Comment: @CommonWare, thx! so both could be used for checking whether the intent could be used for `startActivity()`? in my case actually I would like to check if the intent can be used for `startActivity()` and try to avoid the `chooser` if my app's packagename is in the returned info list.

Comment: @lannyf: "so both could be used for checking whether the intent could be used for startActivity()?" -- yes, though you do need to take those package visibility rules into account.

Comment: ya, i have for os>11 `    <queries>
        <intent>           
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>`